# Making operator insert and append repeatable

Tags: vimrc, repeated-commands, operator

Is there an insert and append operation that can be followed by a text-object? I've found this plugins:

https://github.com/deris/vim-operator-insert
https://github.com/mwgkgk/vim-operator-insert

But they seem to be unmaintained. I think these operators are useful as they are easily repeatable, if you `gaiw` (go append in word) you can add something and go to another word and also append it (just pressing `.`), just like with change.

These plugins unfortunately not working with the `.` operator and they also fail to work in visual mode. Is there any available solution? Is there a reason why this is not interesting?

Comment: `ciwTEXT<C-r>"` -- operator insert, `ciw<C-r>"TEXT` -- operator append (though not repeatable).

Comment: @MaximKim macro repeatable though

Comment: having to record a macro is a lot more keystrokes, my goal with this is that ti shall be as intuitive as other operators, so I can literally speak with vim. If I want to append something at the end of a quote, I want to be able to do `gaiq` (go append in quote), I find operators really powerful @D.BenKnoble

Comment: @Blasco not disagreeing.

Answer (score 3):

You can come up with something relatively simple, following and tinkering what vim has described in `:h :map-operator`:

As an example I came up with in about 15 minutes of experimenting:

```
nmap <silent> gi :set opfunc=InsertToTextObject<CR>g@
vmap <silent> gi :<C-U>call InsertToTextObject(visualmode(), 1)<CR>

nmap <silent> ga :set opfunc=AppendToTextObject<CR>g@
vmap <silent> ga :<C-U>call AppendToTextObject(visualmode(), 1)<CR>

function! InsertToTextObject(type, ...)
    let sel_save = &selection
    let &selection = "inclusive"
    let reg_save = @@

    if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use gv command.
        silent exe "normal! gv"
    else
        silent exe "normal! `["
    endif

    startinsert

    let &selection = sel_save
    let @@ = reg_save
endfunction


function! AppendToTextObject(type, ...)
    let sel_save = &selection
    let &selection = "inclusive"
    let reg_save = @@

    if a:0
        silent exe "normal! `>"
        call feedkeys('a', 'n')
    elseif a:type == 'line'
        silent exe "normal! ']"
        call feedkeys('A', 'n')
    else
        silent exe "normal! `]"
        call feedkeys('a', 'n')
    endif

    let &selection = sel_save
    let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

Insert to text object is really simple -- you just goto `[` mark and `startinsert`

Append was a bit more difficult, you have to feedkey there, either `a` or `A` depending on linewise selection mode.

See it in action:

[image]

Comment: with tpope/repeat, you can make this dot-repeatable (I think)

Comment: Great work, amazing! I think the plugin I linked does something similar. The problem is that it is not repeatable, I'm trying to add tpope/repeat support as suggested by @D.BenKnoble

Comment: Making it repeatable doesn't seem to be straight forward. This is some advice from tpope https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat/issues/75

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Almost there, I've post an answer. I manage to repeat the a different operator which pastes the content of the `@.` register, this is repeatable, but we need to include the range the first time we want to repeat, which is no that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm almost there, maybe can use this as inspiration to make it work. I'm making use of kana/operator-user as in the suggested plugins.

The problem is entering insert mode during the repetition, so I've created a different operator to repeat using paste:

```
if exists('g:loaded_operator_insert')
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_operator_insert = 1

let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim


call operator#user#define('insert-i', 'operator#insert#insert_i')
call operator#user#define('insert-a', 'operator#insert#insert_a')
call operator#user#define('insert-i-repeat', 'operator#insert#insert_i_repeat')
call operator#user#define('insert-a-repeat', 'operator#insert#insert_a_repeat')


let &cpo = s:save_cpo
unlet s:save_cpo
```

Which works like this:

```
let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

" Public API {{{1

function! operator#insert#insert_i(motion_wise)
    return s:operator_insert_i(a:motion_wise)
endfunction

function! operator#insert#insert_a(motion_wise)
    return s:operator_insert_a(a:motion_wise)
endfunction

function! operator#insert#insert_i_repeat(motion_wise)
    return s:operator_insert_i_repeat(a:motion_wise)
endfunction

function! operator#insert#insert_a_repeat(motion_wise)
    return s:operator_insert_a_repeat(a:motion_wise)
endfunction

"}}}

" Private {{{1

function! s:operator_insert_i_repeat(motion_wise)
    let s:original_pos = getpos("'[")[1:]
    call cursor(s:original_pos)
    normal! ".P
endfunction

function! s:operator_insert_a_repeat(motion_wise)
    call cursor(getpos("']")[1:])
    if col("']") >= col("$") - 1
        normal! ".p
    else
        normal! l
        normal! ".p
    endif
endfunction

function! s:operator_insert_i(motion_wise)
    let s:original_pos = getpos("'[")[1:]
    call cursor(s:original_pos)
    startinsert
    silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>(operator-insert-i-repeat)", -1)
endfunction

function! s:operator_insert_a(motion_wise)
    call cursor(getpos("']")[1:])
    if col("']") >= col("$") - 1
        startinsert!
    else
        normal! l
        startinsert
    endif
    silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>(operator-insert-a-repeat)", -1)
endfunction

"}}}

let &cpo = s:save_cpo
unlet s:save_cpo
```

Now it does work, but when we do the `.` we need to reenter the first time the text object. It is not ideal, but something is something.

Comment: I made a plugin built on Blasco's suggestion: https://github.com/bagohart/vim-operator-insert-append

Comment: @bagohart That's great! I'm going to check it out :)

Comment: @bagohart I love the way you have put it together, with the nice explanation in the read me I don't see it as a disadvantage anymore, I think I'm going to use it more often now!